# Prove that $f(x) = x^p-x \leq 0, 0<p<1$, $x\geq 1$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Can someone help me prove this. I am trying to use this function to prove the p-series test for the case $0<p<1$ together with the comparison test. 
I am trying myself, and thought someone may see the logic  immediately.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I have made the correction.

Comment: A Simple argument using the first derivative should suffice. Can you try to work it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_p(x) = x^p -x$.
It is clear that $f_p(1)=0$ and you can show that $f_p'(x) <0$ for all $x \ge 1$.

So you have a decreasing function with $f_p(1)=0$, so $f_p(x)$ is $\dots$ for all $x \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

we have $0< 1-p <1$.

$$f(x)=x^p-x=x^p(1-x^{1-p})$$

If suffices to see that $x^{1-p} \geq 1$

This is true since $x \geq 1$.